# Deviation from Hardy Weinberg equilibrium (HWE)

Tags: population-genetics, gene, statistics

I have a set of 10 genes, each gene contains around 15 SNPs. I have tested the deviation from Hardy Weinberg equilibrium (HWE) for all SNPs. All of the SNPs didn't deviate from HWE, except 5 SNPs in ABCG8, they had p<0.05. I have found different factors that can affect the HWE. My question: Why for the rest of the SNPs met the HWE, why only 5 SNPs in ABCG8 deviate largely from HWE?

Comment: Be careful with the claims based on p-values: **a p-value allows to reject the null hypothesis, but not to confitm it**. In other words, when $p<0.05$ one can say that HWE is broken, however $p>0.05$ does not mean that HWE holds - it could be still broken, but we cannot prove it.

Comment: I would quibble with @Vadim a bit- when you do 150 tests, you expect that $0.05 * 150 = 7.5$ SNPs to be $p < 0.05$, as under the null hypothesis, p-values from independent tests are uniformly distributed. P-values are a quite low standard of evidence except when they're very small. Having all 5 occur in one gene might be surprising, but nonetheless I would say that "rejecting" the null hypothesis based on it is a bit strong, as the observations are still pretty consistent with the null hypothesis (without seeing additional data).

Comment: @MaximilianPress I was talking about more basic difference about p-value and power, objecting the claim that *the rest of the SNPs met the HWE*. However I do agree with you that, given the large number of tests, even the five SNPs with $p<0.05$ are not a proof that HWE is violated.

Comment: @Vadim ok, that makes sense. I agree with your overall point about p-values used to confirm the null hypothesis, I think I was just worried about the other side of the issue, which wasn't clear. I think that you actually addressed the question quite directly and accurately! I would suggest making it into an answer, actually.

Answer (score 2):

A *significance test* (i.e., p-value) allows us to reject the null hypothesis, but not to confirm it. In other words, when $p<0.05$ one can say that the conditions for HWE are not met, however $p>0.05$ does not mean that HWE holds - the conditions might still not be met, but we cannot prove it. Thus, by making statements such as *All of the SNPs didn't deviate from HWE* and *the rest of the SNPs met the HWE* one may be committing [Type II statistical error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors).

As @MaximilianPress correctly pointed out, in this case one should not be making any statements about the SNPs with $p<0.05$ either, due to the high possibility of [False discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate). Indeed, a p-value gives us the probability that the data would be at least as extreme as was observed, even though the null hypothesis is true. Given $N=150$ SNPs one expects about $$N\times\alpha = 150 \times 0.05= 7.5$$ statistically significant outcomes to occur by chance, even if the HWE holds. That is, one could be also committing the Type I error of rejecting the null hypothesis, when it is true. To exclude this error one needs to use a more stringent test, e.g., [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction), i.e., testing against the significance level $N$ times smaller than the current $\alpha=0.05$:
$$
\alpha\longrightarrow\frac{\alpha}{N}=\frac{0.05}{150}\approx 0.0003
$$